# Arm template rollback feature

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

I am looking for rollback feature in arm template, then I found `-RollbackDeploymentName` on azure docs. But seems like it is not working as expected.

Read some blogs which says in case of error the specified deployment will get run in complete mode, means all the extra resources get deleted, which was not in previous deployment. But I tried the same like below :

Deployed an function app with storage account with dep-1 name.
then in second stage I deployed same script with an public IP address and not available function app name, in that case public IP get deployed and function app get failed. After that azure started an deployment with name `dep-120211222T130210Z` which is same as dep-1. But that does not delete my extra resources, the public IP.

Please help, what I am missing here. Thanks